# Open source ERP system in PHP with POS/HR/payroll/construction/education

Tags: erp

## Problem:

I have given a plan to manage/develop an ERP System of an organization. Our systems run on Ubuntu.

Please help me to choose an erp system for startup

and then obviously it is required custom development and some new modules as well.

### Requirements

- one or more fully custom module that is the main business of the org
- accounts
- hr including hiring and payrol
- sales
- purchases
- pos (including sale points)
- construction management (learning centers, offices etc)
- education (course managements) here may required some or more custom requirements
- departments and offices
- product item can normally be a book, cd or usb etc

### Current Findings

I have explored some erp systems and come to this point that

- **erpnext** is full-filling my most of the requirements including payrol, pos, accounts etc and excluding 1 or 2 modules, which need to build from scratch.
- Also erpnext is offering more free modules
- but **erpnext is build in python and that is not satisfying the condition**.
- It is difficult to hire a senior developer (because we are not a software company or not having a big IT department so developers will not prefer to work here). So we should try for a php-based-erp system, as it is easier to find php developer.

Comment: We are willing to hire one mid level developer other than a manager who will gather requirements and co-ordinate with the developer.